# How to separate jqote2 templates from html file (using own file)

Tags: jquery, jqote

I want to separate my templates which are in a form like:

```
<script type="text/x-jqote-template" id="tpl-header">
<![CDATA[
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Just a demo</h1>
        <a href="/" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" data-direction="reverse" class="ui-btn-right jqm-home">Home</a>
    </div><!-- /header -->
```

I want to move the templates to a separate file (e.g. 'base.tpls') for two reasons:

1. I want to maintain them separately
2. I want to reuse templates in different *.html

I already tried using a script tag with source base.tpls, but it did not work.

Do I need to load the content of 'base.tpls' with javascript/jquery?

Comment: Some more information needed..

Comment: you should use server-side languages to do so.

Comment: for some reason stackoverflow did not accept my initial post sorry for that... @undefined: I need to use client side templating because I want to use html5 offline capabilities with as few files as possible

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version of my handlers, which take in data I download from a link. This ought to get you started, if you're still trying to solve this:

```
var _ = {
    templates: {},
    template: {
        compile: function(id, tmpl) {
            _.templates[id] = $.jqotec(tmpl, "*")
        },
        populate: function(id, data) {
            $.jqote(_.templates[id], data, "*")
        }
    }
}

$.get(
    link,
    function( tmpl ) {
        _.template.compile( id, tmpl )
    }
);

$( element ).append( _.template.populate( id, data ) )
```